# Is there any easy method/systematics method to attain self realization in short time duration?

Tags: mukti

Is there any easy method/systematics method to attain self realization ?

I have read the story of Budhha . He take 5 years to attain self realization

But it is very long time duration . I want to attain self-realization in 5-6 months

Like in education we do Bsc and Msc  and we complete our graduation in systematics manner.

Is there any systematics  method to attain self realization(mukti) ?

Comment: "Is there any easy method/systematics method to attain self realization ?" Yes there is. Pray a lot to the iswar and cross your fingers.

Comment: Well, the purpose of nature itself is self-realization, whether you do it today or billion years after. Buddha didnot take mere 5 years, all of us have taken several births and summation of all your previous birth Karmas is your own horoscope. Buddha told his disciples after realization that he had been searching truth in previous births as well which has ended now. There is no easy method of realization, the reason you are not born self-realized like Jada Bharat or Shukadeva, because nature found you unfit and incapable for handling that state. In Kaliyuga, majority are atheists and corrupt.

Comment: The only pointer I can give, is when the desire of Self or God realization exceeds personal body's survival, than realization happen, you can do that tomorrow or take 100 years depending on your previous Karmic weaknesses. Buddha took 5 years to reach that thirst level when he decided either to realize truth or give up body under the Bodhi tree. Truth realization alone grants the rishihood or seer state, not by mere cramming Vedas or scriptures.